# How to parse a String to a specific Array charactere?

Tags: javascript

In some point, I was able to end this array from my node js server to the navigator page, but it was received as a String so I need to parse it into an array

```
"['Date', 'Call (minutes)'],['Date1', 100],['Date2', 1370],['Date3', 660],['Date4', 1030],['Date5', 1000],['Date6', 1170],['Date7', 660]"
```

***Is there any tool that can help me to parse it into its array form?***

Comment: how do you ends up with this string? probably something can be done before receiving the string on the front end

Comment: You should normally use `JSON.parse` however, your data is not properly formatted. You should properly encode the array via `JSON.stringify` for example. Currently, the problem is that the strings like `'Date'` are not enclosed in double quotes `"` and also you have comma separated arrays instead, it should be an array of arrays.

Comment: why not get a [JSON](https://json.org/) copliant string, which is easily parsable.

Comment: @Berto99 in the end this string, In an array format, will be used in a function provided by google chart, in order to draw a chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace single quotes to double and wrap the string in brackets for getting an array of arrays.

```js
const
    string = "['Date', 'Call (minutes)'],['Date1', 100],['Date2', 1370],['Date3', 660],['Date4', 1030],['Date5', 1000],['Date6', 1170],['Date7', 660]",
    array = JSON.parse(`[${string.replace(/'/g, '"')}]`);

console.log(array);
```

Another approach is to use `eval`, if the data is reliable.

```js
const
    string = "['Date', 'Call (minutes)'],['Date1', 100],['Date2', 1370],['Date3', 660],['Date4', 1030],['Date5', 1000],['Date6', 1170],['Date7', 660]",
    array = eval(`[${string}]`);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced to use this string, then you have to "make it" looks like JSON, but be aware that this is a very **bad idea**, you should **consider doing something else on your backend in order to send JSON strings to the front end**, and not strings with some kind of format.

If you want to risk, you can do something like this:

```js
let res = JSON.parse('[' + "['Date', 'Call (minutes)'],['Date1', 100],['Date2', 1370],['Date3', 660],['Date4', 1030],['Date5', 1000],['Date6', 1170],['Date7', 660]".replaceAll("'", '"') + ']')
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse` to convert string to array.
Here, pls take care on single quotes.
Before using `JSON.parse`, you need to convert single quotes(`'`) to double quotes (`"`).

```js
var str = "['Date', 'Call (minutes)'],['Date1', 100],['Date2', 1370],['Date3', 660],['Date4', 1030],['Date5', 1000],['Date6', 1170],['Date7', 660]";

var parsedArray = JSON.parse(`[${str.replaceAll("'", '"')}]`);
console.log(parsedArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```js
JSON.parse(string);
```

**UPD**:
I didn't notice that JSON-incompatibile single quotes are used.

I'd propose to just replace them with double quotes:

```js
const jsonCompatString = string.replace(/'/g, `"`);
const serverData = JSON.parse(jsonCompatString);
```

Comment: And that will get you nothing, as it's not properly formatted data.

Comment: "*I'd propose to just replace them with double quotes:"* 1. that's not the only problem 2. It's *always* better to produce valid JSON from the start, rather than receive what is essentially an arbitrary string and try to pre-process it into a valid JSON